# Javascript about event registration and event loop confused

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events, event-loop

I tried a long time to figure out, how event and event loop works. I read so many article in internet and books about event registration and event loop, but I still can not imagine how it works.

I am reading the book Async JavaScript from Prgmatic Bookshelft about event queue, you can read in the book an article.

> When we call setTimeout, a timeout event is queued. Then execution
> continues, the code after the setTimeout call runs and so on, until no
> code more left. After then it will start the event loop and detect,
> which event get fired and it will call the handler.

After this article, I have got a bit imagination about event and async in Javascript. Then I tried by myself the following code:

```
setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")},0);

for (var i = 0; i <= 100000; i++) {
    console.log('I am loop');
}
```

I have set the time 0, because I want to have confirmation about this sentence:

> the code after the setTimeout call runs and so on..

and

> After then it will start the event loop and...

until here, everything is fine how event in Javascript; it works. Then I keep continue reading Async JavaScript book, and had read the following:

> Input events work the same way: when a user clicks a DOM element with
> a click handler attached, a click event is queued. But the handler
> won't be executed until all currently running code had finished.

The first sentence sounds for me a bit confused. For example:

```
//Some codes
#("element").click(function(e){
    //Do something
});
//Some codes
```

What I don't understand here is, when the compiler will saved a click event in the event queue? Will it be saved in the queue after registration (after this code) or when I had clicked the element?

In node I tried this code, to figure out how event works. Consider the following code:

```
var events = require("events");
var event = new events.EventEmitter();

event.on('ev1', function () {
    console.log('Into ev1');

});

event.emit('ev1');
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    console.log('I am in the loop');
}

console.log('I am finish with loop');
```

What I am expected here is:

> I am in the loop
> I am in the loop
> I am in the loop
> I am in the loop
> I am in the loop
> I am in the loop
> I am finish with loop
> Into ev1

but what I got it is:

> Into ev1
> I am in the loop
> I am in the loop
> I am in the loop
> I am in the loop
> I am in the loop
> I am in the loop
> I am finish with loop

After this output, it breaks all my imagination about event (async) execution and event loop that I had read in the book and article in the net before. Consider this sentence in the book:

> the code after the setTimeout call runs and so, until no code more
> left. After then it will start the event loop and detect, which event
> get fired and it will call the handler.

But why the code above with the `EventEmitter` works opposite? I thought the event loop will be execute at the end (after other codes be done).

I had read in internet about database (for example mongoose) query with node is async. I don't know how async database query definitively works, but I am imagining like this:

[image: Database request and response]

Please explain me, how events in Javascript really work?

Comment: `EventEmitter` and it's `emit` method is a different kind of event to the one for user input events in the browser, and the one for queued code in node. Here's an article that explains some differences well: http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` is a bit apart from `EventEmitter`, due to which you are getting these results. First of all I would ask you to run these examples first.

Save this in async.html and run it in your browser. Check the console to see the results.

```
<div id="element">
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
setTimeout(function(){console.log("Hello")},0);
$("#element").click(function(e){
    console.log("Inside");
});
$("#element").click();
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log('I am loop');
}
</script>
```

Output

```
Inside
I am loop
I am loop
I am loop
I am loop
I am loop
Hello
```

Now save this in async.js and run this in node.js

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log("Hello")},0);

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log('I am loop');
}
```

Output

```
I am loop
I am loop
I am loop
I am loop
I am loop
Hello
```

You will find that `setTimeout` works a little different than `EventEmitter`. An EventEmitter executes the handler immediately whereas setTimeout attempts to execute it immediately. The actions are not performed until the next tick. Read about it [here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth#the-settimeout-func-0-trick).

Do not mix setTimeout with EventEmitter.

#### Edit

Your example does not demonstrate asynchrony quite well. You are simply running a loop inside the event handler. Here is a more clear example :

```
var events = require("events");
var event = new events.EventEmitter();

event.on("work", function (i,cb) {
    console.log('Started '+i );
    setTimeout(function(){event.emit("done",i,cb);},Math.random()*1000);
});

event.on("done", function (i,cb) {
    cb(i);
});

var async = function (cb) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        emitclosure(i,cb);
    }
}

function emitclosure(i,cb){
        setTimeout(function(){event.emit("work",i,cb)},Math.random()*1000);
}

async(function (i) {
    console.log("I have done "+i);
});
```

I would point out that I use `setTimeout` along with events only to give a feel of delay of arrival of work and processing delay, unlike their synonymous use in the question. `emitclosure` is just a closure for loop variables, so that their scope is safe.

Comment: when i fired an event on EventEmitter it will execute the callback immediately right? How async database works? Please show some example about async.

Comment: Whats mean this: The actions are not performed until the next tick? What is next tick?

Comment: You could read http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/ and http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick to know more about event loop and next tick. As you know node.js is event-driven and asynchronous. So events are used to handle everything, even database queries/transactions are implemented with events. It is pretty much like the `click` event handler above except that the `click` event is triggered by the database driver. You just specify what function executes on that event.

Comment: is this code async?`code`var events = require("events");

var event = new events.EventEmitter();


event.on("work", function () {

    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        console.log("I do my work " + i);
    }

    event.emit("done");
});

var async = function (cb) {

    event.on("done", cb);
    event.emit("work");
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        console.log("Async " + i);
    }
}


async(function () {
    console.log("I am done callback!");
});